# What do I have to do for opening and editing existing file with PHP?

Tags: html, file

I have different HTML files. I want to open, edit and then save changes with PHP (NOT OOP) in admin panel by using HTML textarea tag. What do I have to do for that? Do I need to create new mysql database? Could you please show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the contents of the HTML file using `file_get_contents`:

```
$html = 'example.html';
$currentContents = file_get_contents($html);

// set the textarea text to $currentContents
```

To write the changes, you will have to post the textarea to a PHP script (through an HTML form) and then do something like:

```
$newContents = $_POST['textareaName'];
$html = 'example.html';
$fh = fopen($html, 'w') or die("File could not be opened.");
fwrite($fh, $newContents);
fclose($fh);
```

There are some security things you need to worry about it, but this is a basic example of how to achieve your goal. Good luck!

http://us.php.net/file_get_contents

http://us.php.net/fwrite